# how to only select links that have text and no picture links

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery. This would be no problem for me using XPath expressions, but how can I do this the 'jQuery' way?

Given the following example:

```
<stuff>
    <a href="target.html">ASDF</a>
    <a href="target.html"><img src="asdf.png" /></a>
</stuff>
```

How can i select with jQuery only the text links and leave the links with the img tags untouched?

Help me j Query kenobi, you are my only hope ;)

Princess Lia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$('a:not(:has(img))')

Comment: Thx a lot
May the source be with you Daniel ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a:not(img)')
```

That should do the job.